# Add leading 0's to a character string

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm working in Marketing Cloud and we have member ID numbers that have 11 characters in one Master table but the leading 0's are dropped in the other table when imported in. I'm looking to add either one or two leading 0's depending on the length of the member ID in the imported table to equal 11 characters, like the Master. Any idea on how to go about this in SQL?

Comment: ensures its a text field

Comment: I confirmed it's text. The 0's are dropped from the other system the data's coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the number you want to pad is stored in a column called `YourNumber` and you want to achieve a length of 3 characters. So for example *7* would be transformed into *007*. To make this happen the target column must be of the Text data type (as @EazyE suuggested) - otherwise any added 0s will disappear.

Padding a number with leading zeros if you think about them as a string. You need to do just two string operations to make this happen:

- you need to add a a number of zeroes close to the number of characters you want to achieve:

```sql
Concat('000', YourNumber)
```

- the resulting string needs to be shortened to the desired length - for this we will use the Right(string, length) function that gives you a substring of a desired length starting from the right side of a number. Combined with the code from the first step, we arrive at:

```sql
Right(Concat('000', YourNumber), 3)
```

We don't know if `YourNumber` is nullable, but if it is, you will need to conditionally fight against padding nulls or empty strings.